# rc-status for System V

Tags: server, init

I'm used to use `rc-status` to check so all the services that should start at init, is still running.

But as I also have a ubuntu server to look after now, and it seams to use systemv, how do i get that type of list?

If I run `service --status-all` I get a list of all, including services thats not suppose to be started, so can't see if a service flagged as stopped, never was intended to start, or if it had a problem and stopped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu >= 15.10, That command is left for compatibility reason only after moving to `systemd`. Use the below command instead:

```
systemctl list-units -t service
```

**Reference:** `man systemctl`

Comment: No good for finding out what services didn't start, as they not even in the list.